# Firebase - Download specific child (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have attached a picture of my JSON tree

```
{
  "-Ko4cg3ik5OFsnLTI4q4" : {
    "FacebookPage" : {
      "id" : "187736205061418",
      "page" : "partyunlimitedtoronto"
    },
    "MapView" : {
      "Edate" : 523940400,
      "Sdate" : 523929600,
      "intersted" : 3843,
      "lat" : 45.510772273476,
      "lng" : -73.563586483671,
      "type" : "MUSIC",
      "userID" : 1373802105986614,
      "visibility" : "Public"
    },
    "address" : "Théâtre Corona",
    "bio" : "evenko & Greenland Productions présentent\t\nMogwai\navec/with Xander Harris \nPortes: 19h00 - Spectacle: 20h00\n\nMise en vente: 24 mars à 10h\n\n37$ à 42$\n\nPrix lors de l’achat à la billetterie / Des frais de manutention peuvent s’appliquer lors de l’achat en ligne.\n\n.....................................................\n\nDoors: 7:00 pm - Show: 8:00 pm\n\nOn Sale: March 24 at 10am\n\n$37 to $42\n\nPrices for box office purchase / Handling fees may apply for online purchase.",
    "name" : "Mogwai // Montréal",
    "pic" : "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17361785_10155183713782422_6829705267219994059_n.jpg?oh=150f6f53c74233b70b7f1b372c1db1e4&oe=59CF07EE",
    "site" : "http://www.evenko.ca/fr/evenements/12392/mogwai/theatre-corona/12-06-2017",
    "status" : "normal"
  },
  "-Ko4cgP2rXJCIRBODWpm" : {
    "FacebookPage" : {
      "id" : "620998508097068",
      "page" : "partyunlimitedtoronto"
    },
    "MapView" : {
      "Edate" : 43223454,
      "Sdate" : 65837495,
      "interested" : 2355,
      "lat" : 45.3846583,
      "lng" : -74.4736583,
      "type" : "Party",
      "userID" : 1373802105986614,
      "visibility " : "Public"
    },
    "address" : "Théâtre Corona",
    "bio" : "Greenland Productions & evenko présentent\t\t\t\t\t\t\nNazareth\t\t\t\navec/with Les Deuxluxes\t\n\nPortes: 19h00 - Spectacle: 20h00\n\nMise en vente: 14 avril à midi \n\n44,50$ à 48$\n\nPrix lors de l’achat à la billetterie / Des frais de manutention peuvent s’appliquer lors de l’achat en ligne.\n\n.....................................................\n\nDoors: 7:00 pm - Show: 8:00 pm\n\nOn Sale: April 14 at noon\n\n$44,50 to $48\n\nPrices for box office purchase / Handling fees may apply for online purchase.",
    "name" : "Nazareth // Montréal",
    "pic" : "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17759677_10155255160737422_1735715699829358715_n.jpg?oh=1d6d1c250c2c6b38c6ef0de4483bd0a9&oe=5A0C4879",
    "site" : "http://www.evenko.ca/fr/evenements/12489/nazareth/theatre-corona/08-03-2017",
    "status" : "normal"
  }
}
```

So I'm attempting to only download the "MapView" node inside every child when I run my program but in this case, I won't know the name of the parent of "MapView". Is there any way to only download a specific child like in this case. Otherwise, I was thinking whether I should use this style of structuring.

```
{
  "EventView" : {
    "-Ko4cg3ik5OFsnLTI4q4" : {
      "FacebookPage" : {
        "id" : "187736205061418",
        "page" : "partyunlimitedtoronto"
      },
      "address" : "Théâtre Corona",
      "bio" : "evenko & Greenland Productions présentent\t\nMogwai\navec/with Xander Harris \nPortes: 19h00 - Spectacle: 20h00\n\nMise en vente: 24 mars à 10h\n\n37$ à 42$\n\nPrix lors de l’achat à la billetterie / Des frais de manutention peuvent s’appliquer lors de l’achat en ligne.\n\n.....................................................\n\nDoors: 7:00 pm - Show: 8:00 pm\n\nOn Sale: March 24 at 10am\n\n$37 to $42\n\nPrices for box office purchase / Handling fees may apply for online purchase.",
      "name" : "Mogwai // Montréal",
      "pic" : "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17361785_10155183713782422_6829705267219994059_n.jpg?oh=150f6f53c74233b70b7f1b372c1db1e4&oe=59CF07EE",
      "site" : "http://www.evenko.ca/fr/evenements/12392/mogwai/theatre-corona/12-06-2017",
      "status" : "normal"
    },
    "-Ko4cgP2rXJCIRBODWpm" : {
      "FacebookPage" : {
        "id" : "620998508097068",
        "page" : "partyunlimitedtoronto"
      },
      "address" : "Théâtre Corona",
      "bio" : "Greenland Productions & evenko présentent\t\t\t\t\t\t\nNazareth\t\t\t\navec/with Les Deuxluxes\t\n\nPortes: 19h00 - Spectacle: 20h00\n\nMise en vente: 14 avril à midi \n\n44,50$ à 48$\n\nPrix lors de l’achat à la billetterie / Des frais de manutention peuvent s’appliquer lors de l’achat en ligne.\n\n.....................................................\n\nDoors: 7:00 pm - Show: 8:00 pm\n\nOn Sale: April 14 at noon\n\n$44,50 to $48\n\nPrices for box office purchase / Handling fees may apply for online purchase.",
      "name" : "Nazareth // Montréal",
      "pic" : "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17759677_10155255160737422_1735715699829358715_n.jpg?oh=1d6d1c250c2c6b38c6ef0de4483bd0a9&oe=5A0C4879",
      "site" : "http://www.evenko.ca/fr/evenements/12489/nazareth/theatre-corona/08-03-2017",
      "status" : "normal"
    }
  },
  "MapView" : {
    "-Ko4cg3ik5OFsnLTI4q4" : {
      "Edate" : 534312000,
      "Sdate" : 534301200,
      "intersted" : 652,
      "lat" : 45.4827983,
      "lng" : -73.575107687761,
      "type" : "MUSIC",
      "userID" : "1373802105986614",
      "visibility" : "Public"
    },
    "-Ko4cgP2rXJCIRBODWpm" : {
      "Edate" : 523508400,
      "Sdate" : 523497600,
      "intersted" : 382,
      "lat" : 45.4827983,
      "lng" : -73.575107687761,
      "type" : "MUSIC",
      "userID" : "1373802105986614",
      "visibility" : "Public"
    }
  }
}
```

where in this case I would have the information in a separate child but where there are parent nodes with the same name in both EventView and MapView.

Comment: can you give a sample code to help us streamline your query.

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I updated pictures to text

Comment: When using an SDK to access Firebase, you're always going to download complete nodes. You cannot request "just the MapView" from each child. If you want that, create a collection (i.e. `MapViews`) where you keep just the map view data. So that's closest to your second structure. This type of data flattening is a common recommendation when using the Firebase Database and has many advantages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For the First structure**

This structure will definitely make our query download the whole EventView node

```
var AllMapViews = []; //<-- array of all mapview objects

var path = "/EventView";
firebase.database().ref(path)
                .once("value")
                .then(eventViews => {

                    eventViews.forEach(thisevent => {

                       AllMapViews.push(thisevent.val().MapView);

                    })
                });
```

> Hence the result of the above will look like this

```
AllMapViews = [
{ "EventDate":343,"Sdate" : 65837495 ..},
{ "EventDate":343,"Sdate" : 65837495 ..},
{ "EventDate":343,"Sdate" : 65837495 ..},
...
]
```

**For the Second structure** (My Choice)

This structure will allow our query download only MapViews for all EventViews. Hence, making it the structure of choice in your implementation. Though it will need you to monitor the main EventView nodes often to know when the main event is deleted so that you can also delete it's corresponding MapView.

```
var AllMapViews = []; //<-- array of all mapview objects

    var path = "/MapViews";
    firebase.database().ref(path)
                    .once("value")
                    .then(mapViews => {

                        mapViews.forEach(map => {

                           AllMapViews.push(map.val());

                        })
                    });
```

> Hence the result of the above will look like this

```
AllMapViews = [
{ "EventDate":343,"Sdate" : 65837495 ..},
{ "EventDate":343,"Sdate" : 65837495 ..},
{ "EventDate":343,"Sdate" : 65837495 ..},
...
]
```

Comment: that would work but in this case, i don't know all the eventIDs because I'm trying to download all the events but only the MapView section in each event

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!! this method would still require me to download the entire database and then separate the MapView locally. For the purposes of network optimization, I'm trying to figure out a way for it to just download the MapView section.

Comment: ok... Wow... considering this new requirement to avoid downloading the entire database we have to go for the second structure... I will also update my answer to show you how to query that.